# Angular JS 2.0 switch stylesheets based on User Input

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms

How can I switch the stylesheets based on the button click in an AngularJS 2.0 application?

As right now I am including stylesheets on the head section of index.html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component({
  selector: ...,
  template: ...,
  styles: [`
:host(:not(.some-class)) {
  border: solid 1px red;
}
:host(.some-class) {
  border: solid 3px green; 
}

`
]})
export class MyComponent {
  @HostBinding('class.some-class') isSomeClass = true;
}
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/95uSto?p=preview)

Comment: On the first part do we have to include both html files in index .html?? and you are defining the class properties in component decorator itself that I dont want...I want to define all styles in css file e.g on.css and off.css  so on the user click I want to change stylesheets..

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "both html files". We are talking about CSS right, or do you want different templates as well? You can move this style to external files and use `styleUrls` instead of course but they are both loaded at once. It might be advantageous to just have one style file and put everthing in. I think the bigger file size is less of a burden than individual requests to the server to fetch the files.

Comment: Actually this is my requirement to maintain 2 css files e.g dark and light styles css so based on user I have to change the stylesheets. As I have seen your plunker example, i think it will solve my problem.thanks for the help !!

Comment: Hi, I am using styleurls to change a css file on click of toggle button as you had made plunker but its not working in case of styleUrls when I am using...Do I have to change in HostBinding syntax as well??

Comment: I don't think you can change a `styleUrls` file on click. If you just move the CSS from my example to **one** CSS file and point to it using `styleUrls` it should work the same.

Comment: But I already added classes in my html elements and I have css where I had defined the properrties of that classes...but now I am trying to change the css on button click...as i said earlier I have two css files but with same class structure as I am using in my html elements but they contains different properties...!!

Comment: Can you update the Plunker of my answer to reflect your situation?

Comment: Can you see the changes I had done...or this is the link  https://plnkr.co/edit/VZ8IOQZkjW1dKKyBJzhN?p=preview

Comment: Seems it doesn't contain all changes. It only has an additional button that doesn't do anything.

Comment: I had added two css files : on.css and off.css...and when I am clicking 'click me' button I want to change the bg color of toggle button which is defined in css files and I am using 'test' class for this toggle button..on every click of ' click me' i want to swap the css files

Comment: Ohh really sorry I didnt see...there is any alternative to do this??

Comment: As far as I know only what is demonstrated in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would leverage the ngStyle directive:

```
<h1 [ngStyle]="{'font-style': style, 'font-size': size, 'font-weight': weight}">
  Change style of this text!
</h1>
<div (click)="changeStyle()">Update style</div>
```

Updading the `style`, `size` values from a method (linked to a click event) will update your style:

```
export class SomeComponent {
  style = 'normal';
  weight = 'normal';
  size = '20px';

  changeStyle($event: any) {
    this.style = 'italic';
 }
```

Comment: I have two stylsheets and based on user input I have to switch the entire style sheet...i dont want to define on component side...!!

Comment: I totally agree that we can update it by calling method but you are not switching style sheets , you are defining the styles in method  and calling it for change.